# Cannot access $_POST data after successful post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have the following **Ajax request**:

```
function send(){
//selected Pictures: some int array
var jsonArray = JSON.stringify(selectedPictures);

var request;
request = $.ajax({
url: "targetPage.php",
type: "POST",
data: {data: jsonArray},
cache: false
});}
```

**I submit it via**

```
href="targetPage.php" onclick="send();"
```

I want to access the array in an HTML file or PHP script and include this in the HTML.
When I check the HTTP traffic with my browser's development tool, I see that the POST actually works fine and the correct array data is sent, however when I want to **access the data with**:

```
if(isset($_POST['data'])){
  $data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));
}
```

nothing happens because the isset returns false. It seems there is some kind of runtime or execution order issue that I'm missing.

Comment: Is that the only code in cycle2-tile.php?

Comment: where is the html? Is there an input named "data"?

Comment: data is in the data directove of the AJAX @Dan

Comment: Not a duplicate @watcher - the OP here is not missing a comma.

Comment: Sorry, edited cycle2-tile.php to here correctly targetPage.php. No it's embedded in an HTML file, however I tried it also as a standalone PHP script and include that one in an HTML file. Both ways did not work.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? Is targetPage.php in the same folder as cycle2-tile.php?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your href, it makes your browser navigate to that page without sending information so you have yo remove it; because you are making the call though an ajax call.

So:

```
<a href="#" onclick="send();"></a>
```

If you want the page to be redirected after the call you should add the success function to the ajax call:

```
function send(){
    //selected Pictures: some int array
    var jsonArray = JSON.stringify(selectedPictures);

    var request;
    request = $.ajax({
        url: "targetPage.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {data: jsonArray},
        cache: false,
        success: function() { location.href = "targetPage.php"; }
     });
}
```

Comment: But I have to navigate to that page afterwards or a different page and want to do both with one click.

Comment: then you can add a function on success of the ajax call:

`success: function() { location.href = "targetPage.php"; }`

Comment: Hey thanks, I think we are on the right track. But still, I cannot access the passed variable.

Comment: You have to know that doing this you will have two requests to the same page, but the first one should have the passed variable.

Answer (score 0):

**IF YOU WANT TO POST AND REDIRECT YOU CAN DO THIS:**

```
<form method="post" action="http://localhost/DLFin/welcome.php" id="my_form">
    <input type="hidden" id="name" name="name">
</form>
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
 function send(){
        //selected Pictures: some int array
        var jsonArray = JSON.stringify(selectedPictures);

        var request;
        request = $.ajax({
            url: "targetPage.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {data: jsonArray},
            cache: false,
            success: function() {  $('#name').val('sajal');
        $('#my_form').submit(); }
         });
    }
```